# How to do the counting between numbers faster?

Tags: math

How many numbers are there between $200$ and $600$ that are divisible by 4,5 and 6?
I know the divisibility rule of 4,5 and 6 but the problem is with counting
How to do that faster?

Comment: Faster than what?  Show us your base-line

Comment: How is this a programming question? Are you asking strictly from a math standpoint?

Comment: This would take a computer just a few microseconds, isn't that fast enough? If you mean how would a *human* do it faster -- that would be off-topic (and the answer would be: don't count at all -- use the inclusion/exclusion principle).

Comment: @John Coleman, takes Python 109 microseconds: `sum([e%4 + e%5 + e%6 == 0 for e in range(200, 601)])`

Comment: @Andrei I think OP meant "divisible by 4, 5, *or* 6". Otherwise -- just check for divisibility by the least common multiple of 60. Also, when I microbenchmark `sum((200:600 %% 4 == 0) | (200:600 %% 5 == 0) | (200:600 %% 6 == 0)))` in R I get a mean of 29 microseconds.

Comment: @John Coleman, I think you're quite right. Let's see if the question gets corrected. There is an algorithm with O(1) complexity then as well: f(4) + f(5) + f(6) - f(lcm(4,5)) - f(lcm(5,6)) - f(lcm(4,6)) + f(lcm(4,5,6)), where f(n) counts how many numbers are divisible by n. My guess is, if implemented programmatically, it will be slower than the "brute force" solution for the 401 numbers that we have here.

Comment: @John Coleman, summation in place of logical operators takes a toll. `sum([(e%4 or e%5 or e%6) == False for e in range(200, 601)])` (when counting 4,5, and 6) is only 60 microseconds.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 0):

Let me answer the first part of the question: 7 if we include 600 :)